# GitHub: What does checkout do?

Tags: github

I'm coming from a perforce background, trying to understand gitHub.

In Perforce when I "checkout" something it lets other users know I am working on that file.  Does checkout work the same way in Git?

It seams like you don't check out files but branches?

Thanks

Comment: Checkout switches to the last commit on the given branch. It changes your files over to the versions on that branch, and makes any new commits apply to that branch.

Comment: (Following along in a tutorial might be worthwhile.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`checkout` in Perforce would roughly equate to `clone` in git, but in VCS like git ( and even SVN ), the checkout doesn't signal lock to others that you are working on it. Anyone can clone a git repo and work on it without thinking about who else is working on it.

Answer (score 4):

In general, checking out a branch does not mean anyone gets notified. It simply means you are switching from one branch of code to another, potentially also creating a new branch in the process depending on your arguments.

For more info about checkout, see [`git checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) documentation.